# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'column_name' in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table

Laravel Multiple Data Insert Error

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'unit_id' at row 2 (SQL: insert into `product_prices` (`created_at`, `product_id`, `unit_id`, `updated_at`) values (2016-12-06 06:56:01, 27, 1,2016-12-06 06:56:01), (2016-12-06 06:56:01,27, , 2016-12-06 06:56:01))

But my `unit_id` field in `nullable();`
Please someone help me
Here `column_name=unit_id`

Comment: include your php code.

Comment: Just paste your SQL structure,  I had a similar problem, I just created the title field as int in db, my bad

Answer (score 8):

First of all, ignore the incorrect "datetime" part. It seems like a bug in the error message. Your concern must be the actual type (int) and the actual column name (unit_id).

And now it gets pretty clear: while unit_id expects an integer value, your code supplies something else. An empty string in your case.

If you don't have any value, you must provide `null` instead of empty string, so the query would look like

```
 ... ('2016-12-06 06:56:01',27, null, '2016-12-06 06:56:01'))
```

Comment: i try to insert using null but it automatic view the blank or empty
 
Same error 

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'unit_id' at row 2 (SQL: insert into product_prices (created_at, product_id, unit_id, updated_at) values (2016-12-06 06:56:01, 27, 1,2016-12-06 06:56:01), (2016-12-06 06:56:01,27, , 2016-12-06 06:56:01))

Comment: @Al-Amin can you provide the table create statement please

Comment: product Price Table

`public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('unit_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->foreign('unit_id')->references('id')->on('units')->onDelete('restrict');
       });
    }`

Comment: Thanks for response, Sorry for too late

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same issue and in my case it was a silly mistake in my controller.

What I did was I returned the whole object instead of just the id, like so:

```
  public function store($id, Request $request) {

    $post = Post::find($id);

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->text = $request->comment;
    $comment->post_id = $post; <--- HERE IS THE MISTAKE 
    $comment->post_id = $post->id; <--- HERE IS THE FIX
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();

    $comment->save();

    return back();

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `intval()` function can solve the problem quite well.

```
intval($unit_id);
```

This code will return `0` if:

- `$unit_id` is not set.
- `$unit_id` is string and not alphanumeric (e.g. `'abc'`).
- `$unit_id` is `NULL`

If `$unit_id` is alphanumeric string (e.g `'10'`), it'll return the number.

Answer (score 1):

You are using unit_id is it referenced with units(`id`) ?. You are inputing a empty value for a foregin key referenced column.use  **null** and  not **''**

```
 insert into product_prices (created_at, product_id, unit_id, updated_at)
  values (2016-12-06 06:56:01, 27, 1,2016-12-06 06:56:01), 
         (2016-12-06 06:56:01,27,null, 2016-12-06 06:56:01);
```

Comment: Check whether you are insert includes all columns in the table or change the query to this and try.

insert into product_prices (created_at, product_id, unit_id, updated_at)
  values (2016-12-06 06:56:01, 27, 1,2016-12-06 06:56:01);
insert into product_prices (created_at, product_id, unit_id, updated_at)
 values (2016-12-06 06:56:01,27,null, 2016-12-06 06:56:01);

Answer (score 1):

Set 0 for `unit_id` before query, if it **null/empty**. See example:

```
if(!isset($unit_id) || empty($unit_id)) $unit_id = 0;
.
.
//insert query rest code
```

Comment: Thanks,
this way i can already solve the problem, But this is not wright way, Hopefully if nay better solution please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same error. update_at and created_at are automatically created by migration. Backup your model and delete it. Then create a new Model using php artisan
   use 
           php artisan make:model Model Name -m
then in your migration table add the fields you need eg.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('airline');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

then do the migration
   php artisan migrate

Comment: If you do not want to create `updated_at` and `created_at` or let's say you have an insert query that does not include these columns. Just write `protected $timestamps = false;` in your model and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

i can solve it, check your payload when sent request put or post to your api

i should send this json:

```
{
...,
"item":1
}
```

but i sent this. this is my mistake

```
{
...,
"item":[{"id"=1}]
}
```

or
    {
    ...,
    "item":[1]
    }

my code in laravel is this:

```
   $item= Item::find($request->input('item'));
   $client->item()->associate($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a validator function like so:

```
function if_set($v)
    if (isset($_POST[$v]) and $_POST[$v] != '')
        $data_to_db[$v] = $_POST[$v];
```