# Laravel "Invalid datetime format :1366"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

Actually I was making a blog with Laravel following a Youtube tutorial (Laravel 5.5). I was adding profile page there was "Name, Designation, Profile pic". I got error as "Invalid datetime format:1366".

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (22007)
>   SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{"id":1,"name":"Sujan Nepal","email":"sujan@gmail.com","created_at":"2018-01-26 16:18:56","updated_at":"2018-01-26 16:18:56"}' for column 'user_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `profiles` (`user_id`, `name`, `designation`, `profile_pic`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ({"id":1,"name":"Sujan Nepal","email":"sujan@gmail.com","created_at":"2018-01-26 16:18:56","updated_at":"2018-01-26 16:18:56"}, Sujan Nepal, Developer, http://localhost/myblog/public/uploads/IMG_0251.JPG, 2018-01-29 16:53:31, 2018-01-29 16:53:31))

Actually I think it arise because of inserting image, but I could not solve it.

Please suggest me how to solve this.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Can you show as the code? As it seems like you're not building your query right - you're specifying the whole model serialized as JSON as the first argument in your SQL query (so you're trying to insert a record which has `id` of `{"id":1,"Name":"..",etc.}` and that messes up the whole query.

Comment: $profiles = new profile;
     $profiles->user_id = Auth::user();
     $profiles->name = $request->input('name');
     $profiles->designation = $request->input('designation');

     if(Input::hasFile('profile_pic')){
      $file = Input::file('profile_pic');
      $file->move(public_path(). '/uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
      $url = URL::to("/").'/uploads/'. $file->getClientOriginalName();
      
     }
     $profiles->profile_pic = $url;
     $profiles->save();

Comment: Schema:  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('designation');
            $table->string('profile_pic');           
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code in your comments, you have this line:

```
$profiles->user_id = Auth::user();
```

That should instead be:

```
$profiles->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

What's happening here is you're setting the `user_id` attribute to the entire `User` object returned from `Auth::user()`. The object probably uses `toString()` when it hits the database driver which looks like it serializes into a json string.

Comment: i can solve it please  check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61901361/308578

Answer (score 0):

For New Comer Like Me , You have to Check

```
{{ $party->id }}
```

Party variable from Party Model. You have to pass the

```
id
```

with this. CHeck sure in your blade. Just Pass The

> id through variable.

Hope You! Got It.