# SQLSTATE[22007] error when inserting data into 2 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert data into 2 separate tables here;
first, it sends it to "***EmpDetails***" then "***Employees***" but gives an error which I've included a screenshot of.

I've spent hours searching for a solution and haven't found a solution or I'm looking at the wrong sources.

[Error when inserting data into ***Employee*** table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWzqF.png)

I've disabled the default timestamp in models and it's still the same. Could someone please help me here, I'm short on time and need some quick help please and thank you.

```
$empDetail = new EmpDetail();


    
    $empDetail -> cnic = $registerRequest->EmployeeCnic;
    $empDetail -> city = $registerRequest->EmployeeNumber;
    $empDetail -> address = $registerRequest->EmployeeCity;
    $empDetail -> phone = $registerRequest->EmployeeAddress;
    $empDetail -> designation = $registerRequest->EmployeeDesignation;

    $emp = $empDetail -> save();

    $emp = new Employee();
    



    $emp -> name = $registerRequest->EmployeeName;
    $emp -> details = EmpDetail::where('cnic','=', $registerRequest->EmployeeCnic)->first();

    $res = $emp -> save();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[22007\]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'column\_name' in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989702/sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1366-incorrect-integer-value-column)

Comment: I saw that and I don't think I called the whole object anywhere, I specified the fields

Comment: what's the migration for the `employees` table?

Comment: Maybe you have different data-type for details column in employees table and why you are adding details in second table if you already have that in first table. you just have to add a foreign key there for a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you made this mistake when you were creating your question but I think that you've misplaced the request names with the wrong database fields (city, address, and phone):

##### Wrong:

```
$empDetail->city = $registerRequest->EmployeeNumber;
$empDetail->address = $registerRequest->EmployeeCity;
$empDetail->phone = $registerRequest->EmployeeAddress;
```

##### Correct:

```
$empDetail->city = $registerRequest->EmployeeCity;
$empDetail->address = $registerRequest->EmployeeAddress;
$empDetail->phone = $registerRequest->EmployeeNumber;
```

*If this isn't the case, then please provide more information from your code for example models, migrations, and controllers that you've used so I can try to recreate it on my machine and provide a useful answer for you.