# Invalid Datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update or insert multiple data when a post approve. Insert condition is working but update function giving error.

> (SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer
> value: '[10000,10000]' for column
> parijattech_web_app.palika_to_school_kriyakalap.cash at row 3 update
> palika_to_school_kriyakalap SET cash = [ 10000, 10000 ],
> palika_to_school_kriyakalap.updated_at = 2022 -12 -26 04: 58: 52 WHERE
> kriya_name IN (SALARY, POSHAK) AND school_id IN (24, 24))

My code is so messy. So, how can i improve my coding skill?

Here is my Controller

```
public function approve(Request $request, $biniyojan_id)
{
    $upudate = DB::table('biniyojan')
    ->where('biniyojan_id', $biniyojan_id)
    ->update(['biniyojan_status' => 1]);

        if ($upudate) {
            $budget_data = BiniyojanDetails::where('biniyojan_id', $biniyojan_id)->where('biniyojan_id', $biniyojan_id)->get();
            $kriya = Palika_ToSchool_Kriyakalap::whereIn('kriya_name', $budget_data->pluck('kriyakalap'))
                ->whereIn('school_id', $budget_data->pluck('school_id'))
                ->get();

            $budget_cash = BiniyojanDetails::where('biniyojan_id', $biniyojan_id)
                ->whereIn('school_id', $kriya->pluck('school_id'))
                ->whereIn('kriyakalap', $kriya->pluck('kriya_name'))
                ->get();

            $updated_bini = $budget_cash->pluck('cash')->toArray();
            $updated_kriya_cash = $kriya->pluck('cash')->toArray();

            $newArray = array_map(function () {
                return array_sum(func_get_args());
            }, $updated_bini, $updated_kriya_cash);

            if ($kriya->pluck('school_id') == $budget_data->pluck('school_id')) {

                Palika_ToSchool_Kriyakalap::whereIn('kriya_name', $budget_data->pluck('kriyakalap'))
                    ->whereIn('school_id', $budget_data->pluck('school_id'))
                    ->update(['cash' => $newArray]);
            } else {

                foreach ($budget_data as $bud) {
                    $data = [
                        'school_id' => $bud->school_id,
                        'kriya_name' => $bud->kriyakalap,
                        'cash' => $bud->cash,
                    ];
                    Palika_ToSchool_Kriyakalap::where('kriya_name' != $bud->kriyakalap)
                        ->insert($data);
                }

            }
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Approved!!!');
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Error!!!');
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[22007\]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'column\_name' in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989702/sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1366-incorrect-integer-value-column)

Comment: No, i have no idea where m i wrong.

Comment: How is the `updated_at` being set? ... it looks like there is an extra space before _both_ hyphens in the date portion, and after _both_ colons in the time portion. `2022 -12 -26 04: 58: 52`.

Comment: There should be mandatory punishment for naming variables or classes spaghetti way like `Palika_ToSchool_Kriyakalap`